# How to remove a specific text in pdf file and save it

Tags: java, pdf

I've got a PDF file which en every single page has a line that i need to remove, i was thinking and finded two ways:

- Use iText or other library to get the job
- Get the byte array from the pdf, then modify it deleting the text and finally save it again

I get the content of the pdf file using:

```
File file = new File(_pdfFile); 
PDDocument document;
try {
    document = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
    pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

    String pages = pdfStripper.getText(document);

    String[] lines = pages.split("\r\n|\r|\n");

    int count=1;
    for(String temp:lines)
    {
        System.out.println(count+" "+temp);
        count++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea how to take it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you rip the text out the PDF you lose all formatting, saving it again will give you something totally different. You’ll need to use a fully fledged PDF library to make edits and preserve formatting.

Comment: Which do you recommend?

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic.

Comment: If you want to remove content parts for good, *redaction* is the feature to look for in a library.

Comment: If the text has a pattern that is consistent enough that it can be expressed as a regular expression. You can automate the process by detecting that text through regex, redact it, then extract the remaining un-redacted text. The LEADTOOLS SDK, for example, has the [DocumentAnalyzer](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/doxa/documentanalyzer.html) Class which can be used to detect and redact the text using regex. This then allows for extracting the remainder and placing in a new PDF document using PDF document classes from the same library (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor).